# pdo where doesnt work?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

im trying some sql on PDO but returning null. Because i have "ı" character on sqlserver table.

for example;

i have "carsname" row on sql table, im trying get this data

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE carsname='ııı'
```

I have a data with name ııı, but the result is null. how can i fix? any help pls.

Comment: What is your table charset? Did you set PDO to use the same charset?

Comment: Show code some actual code.

Comment: @Geoffrey first thanks for reply, i try to utf8_general_ci and utf8_turkish_ci but still returning null.

Comment: No problems. It is certainly an encoding problem, I suggest you use `utf8mb4`. Make sure your table charset is set to this, AND you have selected it in your PDO connection string (`charset=utf8mb4`), then insert your record again to ensure the characters are encoded correctly when they are inserted. Changing the table type after insertion is too late.

Comment: charset=utf8mb4 working well thank you very much !

Comment: No worries, I have posted the solution as an answer so you can mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a compatible encoding on both the table and the client connection. Ensure your table is using `utf8mb4` and your PDO connection is also by specifying the charset in the connection string, ie `charset=utf8mb4`.